# Как убрать action bar и тень под ним, но оставить троеточие

Tags: java, android, activity, android-toolbar

Подскажите, как можно убрать текст в Action bar, но оставить при этом кнопку настроек. Пытался изменить цвет текста в Action bar, но меняется и цвет текста в меню настроек. А также подскажите, как убрать тень под action bar. Может быть, вопросы легкие, но ответа я на них не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто задайте пустой заголовок:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

И вот так уберите тень:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно выбрать `Activity` тему, содержащую текст `NoActionBar` либо в коде прописать:

```
getActionBar().hide()
```

В качестве меню можно использовать PopupMenu:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
  PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
  MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
  popup.show();
}
```

Comment: Popup в моем случае не лучший вариант. Хотелось бы полноценное активити с настройками